# Vault: how to get list of kv secrets

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Why am I getting an empty result when I just wrote an secret to a backend:

```
vault kv write secret/example password=pwd
Success! Data written to: secret/example
```

However, when I'm trying to get some data from my backend:

```
vault kv list secret/example
No value found at secret/spring-example/
```

Comment: Note that you may be able to use the dev web ui to browse your vault and see where your secret went, https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/getting-started/ui

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't use *list* for a single key, you use *get*.

```
vault kv list secret/
```

should list your *example* key, and

```
vault kv get secret/example
```

should display the value of *password*